# Absolutely positioned element inside overflow:auto parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We have a div which has a `max-height` property. Since we want the content to be scrollable we have `overflow:auto` in that div.

But now we need to have a bootstrap dropdown in the content and when the dropdown is activated the menu is rendered inside the container div, it does not pop out of it. How can we fix this?

Here is the replication of the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/broncha/h1pa0tex/

Comment: http://codepen.io/agop/pen/itbew

Comment: @LuukSkeur Thanks. I have been through that example. But that is not the case here. The parent is set to `overflow: auto` not hidden.

Comment: If possible can you share UI or Screenshot...what exact you are looking for ?

Comment: @Broncha, changing `hidden` into `auto` has the same result in the codepen.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq I have posted a jsfiddle. I need the red div popping out of parent container

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is that you cannot!
(If you use `overflow:auto` then everything inside `container` will be scrollable.)

1. If you don't have `overflow` it works:

   ```css
       .container{
         width: 200px;
         background: lightblue;
         padding: 15px;
       }

       .dropdown{
         border: 1px solid #000;
         position: relative;
       }

       .popup{
         position: absolute;
         top: 100%;
         left:0;
         background: red;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <div class="container">
         <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
         <div class="dropdown">
           <p>Content</p>
           <div class="popup">
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   ```
2. If you want exactly what you are striving for, then you have to do `position: fixed` and use js to adjust for the scroll:

   ```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
           var dropDownTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
           $(this).find('.popup').css('top', dropDownTop + "px");
           $(this).find('.popup').css('left', $(this).offset().left - 0.5 + "px");
           $(this).find('.popup').css('width', this.getBoundingClientRect().width - 1 + "px");
         });

       });

       $('div.container').scroll(function() {
         $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
           var dropDownTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
           $(this).find('.popup').css('top', dropDownTop + "px");
           $(this).find('.popup').css('left', $(this).offset().left - 0.5 + "px");
           $(this).find('.popup').css('width', this.getBoundingClientRect().width - 1 + "px");

         });
       });
   ```

   ```css
       body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
       }
       * {
         box-sizing: border-box;
       }
       .container {
         width: 200px;
         max-height: 200px;
         overflow: auto;
         background: lightblue;
         padding: 15px;
       }
       .dropdown {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         position: relative;
       }
       .popup {
         position: fixed;
         background: red;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="container">
         <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
         <div class="dropdown">
           <p>Content</p>
           <div class="popup">
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
             <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <p>asasd asdasdas bnvnbv jgjg khg nbvnbvn nbvn bv</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas nbv mgv mbnv mnbv nbv</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas kuyg k kjhb kjhb</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas jkhg kjhg jhb khg</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas kjhg jhg hjgyg</p>
         <p>asasd asdasdas hkjh jbjhb mv mhv</p>
       </div>
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, but with position fixed you can 'break-out' the main container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <p>Content</p>
    <div class="popup">
      <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
      <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
      <p>asasd asdasdas dasdasda</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<p>asasd asdasdas bnvnbv jgjg khg nbvnbvn nbvn bv</p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas nbv mgv mbnv mnbv nbv</p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas kuyg k kjhb kjhb</p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas jkhg kjhg jhb khg </p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas kjhg jhg hjgyg </p>
  <p>asasd asdasdas hkjh jbjhb mv mhv</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.popup{
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 184px;
}
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/frankspin/pen/YWBRLY)

Comment: Close. But the component is a bootstrap dropdown. This way the dropdown menu detaches from the trigger